# Calculating Averages for an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been trying to calculate averages for parameters stored in `ArrayList` but always seem to receive `0` when calling my `numberAverage` class after adding new `int` objects to the `ArrayList` and I could really do with some help to point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: The mean in the sum of the elements divided by the number of elements. Not its inverse.

Comment: Beside that, rounding and casting to `int` does not make sense for an average.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a typo (the math is inverted)

Comment: Your code is fine but the math is off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did the reverse of what mean actually is. Use this:

```
double mean = ((double)aggregate / numberAverage.size());
```

Comment: Thank you, this was an oversight of mine.

Comment: @Facetoface click on the green tick to accept this as the answer then :-)